# Where results.txt file is saved?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, yolo

I have just finished training my model using yolov3 and I want to access the results for it.
I executed this piece of code:

```
!./darknet detector test data/obj.data cfg/yolov3_custom.cfg /mydrive/yolov3/backup/yolov3_custom_last.weights -thresh 0.3 -iou_thresh 0.50 -points 101 -dont_show -ext_output /mydrive/images/Bribie_10_3_0779.jpg result.txt
```

However, I'm not sure where the txt file was saved to.

I am also using Google Colab to do this.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try to look into the directory from which you executed this code, results.txt should be there.

Comment: they mentioned that they are using Google Colab. I haven't used it before but looking at it right now it seems like they should run `pwd` and then find the files side panel and look for the .txt file they're after.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this command again but with a unique name (example: chicken.txt), then try to find that file in your file explorer.